# Quando usar size_t?

Tags: c, c++, tipagem

Achei [um artigo](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/2/Why-size-t-matters) em inglês que explica muito bem alguns motivos para a existência deste tipo e como usá-lo.

Segundo esse artigo, o tipo serve para representar tamanhos em bytes de objetos, porém sempre vejo em livros e códigos usando o tipo `size_t` em vários lugares que não representam tamanhos.

Então quando devo usar o `size_t` e quais vantagens esse uso pode trazer?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Na verdade não tem um momento exato que você deve usar o size_t. Por ele ser o mesmo que 'unsigned int' você o utiliza em qualquer lugar que você utilizaria um 'unsigned int', a unica diferença é que um 'unsigned int' é mais apropriado para tamanhos, pois por se tratar de um unsigned, todos seus valores que seriam negativos vão para o espaço dos valores positivos o que é melhor já que praticamente não se mede tamanho em bytes com valores negativos. E a vantagem de usar o tipo int é que tamanhos em bytes são medidos em numeros inteiros, não em decimais, assim seria inútil usar float ou double.

O size_t foi feito mais especificamente para ser usado como resultado do operador sizeof, mas ele é geralmente usado também para indexação de arrays e contador de loops(for, while) que são operações que geralmente não usam valores negativos ou decimais.

Então basicamente, a vantagem de usar o size_t é a mesma de usar o 'unsigned int' no local apropriado, mas por uma questão de organização, o size_t é mais usado para representar tamanhos, afinal, não faria sentido usa-lo para outros propósitos se podemos usar o 'uint32_t' que representa a mesma coisa.

Comment: `std::size_t` não é equivalente a `unsigned int` segundo a especificação: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#3

Comment: Olá @MárioFeroldi, Aparentemente link que você citou está quebrado. De qualquer forma, não sei sei você chegou a consultar mais fontes, mas aparentemente desde as padronizações antigas do C como o ISO/IEC 9899 (C99) [link](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=266), na maioria das fontes encontradas na internet e até mesmo no código fonte do GCC [link](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/21350b1beb296202ef6e4d759f209599c7d934aa/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h#L209) o `size_t` é tratado como um `unsigned int`.

Comment: Consegui acessar o link citado, e aparentemente lá esta afirmando a mesma coisa que foi respondido. "The type size_­t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object", ou seja, confirma que `size_t` é uma implementação definida de `unsigned int`

Comment: Erradíssimo. **O que a implementação faz (GCC nesse caso) não é relevante para a padronização**. "Unsigned integer" é **qualquer tipo não sinalizado inteiro**, isto é, pode muito bem ser `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, ou `uint64_t`. Isso é facilmente provado empiricamente se você testar `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(unsigned int)` onde a implementação define `size_t` como `unsigned long long` (e.g., maioria das arquiteturas 64 bit).

Comment: Por favor, corrija a sua resposta.

Comment: FelipeDurar, na especificação que forneceu, [ISO/IEC 9899 (C99)](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=266), veja no paragrafo 4 na mesma página, onde que diz: *...Recommended practice
The types used for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` should not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of signed long int unless the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary...* o que valida o argumento do @MárioFeroldi

Answer (score 13):

> Segundo esse artigo o tipo serve para representar tamanhos em bytes de objetos

Corretíssimo.

As respostas (até o momento da postagem dessa aqui) estão **equivocadas** ao dizerem que `size_t` é equivalente ao primitivo `unsigned int`.

Primeiro, o parágrafo relevante da padronização é o seguinte:

> [[support.types.layout]/3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#3)
>
> The type `size_­t` is an **implementation-defined unsigned integer type** that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([[expr.sizeof]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof)).

As ênfases (minhas) claramente dizem: `size_t` é um tipo inteiro sem sinal. Em outras palavras, `size_t` pode muito bem ser equivalente a `uint16_t`, como também pode ser equivalente a `uint64_t`, ou outros tipos de característica similar. Portanto, `size_t` **não é garantido** de ser equivalente a `unsigned int`. É permitido, sim, mas é diferente de ser garantido. E hoje em dia, com a esmagadora maioria das arquiteturas sendo de 64 bits, o `std::size_t` é definido como `unsigned long long` pelas bibliotecas padrão.

Voltando para a pergunta:

> […] porém sempre vejo em livros e códigos usando o tipo size_t em vários lugares que não representam tamanhos.

`size_t` é normalmente usado pra indexar arranjos (arrays) e fazer contagem em laços (loops). Por quê? Vamos usar um exemplo: ao usar um tipo diferente, como `unsigned int`, para indexar um arranjo, é possível que a operação de indexação falhe em sistemas 64-bit quando o índice exceder o valor de `UINT_MAX`, ou se o índice depende de aritmética modular para voltar ao valor zero após incrementar o índice máximo [<sup>1</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Mas, mesmo assim, o tipo apropriado pra indexar os contêineres (`std::vector`, `std::string` etc) é sempre o membro `::size_type`, um typedef que é dado por tais contêineres (`std::vector<int>::size_type` por exemplo). Normalmente, entretanto, `::size_type` é definido como sinônimo de `size_t` [<sup>1</sup>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). As funções membros `size()` dos contêineres também retornam um `::size_type`.

Answer (score 4):

Eu uso basicamente em 2 situacoes

1) tamanhos para alocacao

```
size_t len;
// calcula len
ptr = malloc(len * sizeof *ptr);
```

2) para indexacao de arrays

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; i++) {
    // work with array[i];
}
```

Comment: Faço uso semelhante. Geralmente, quando estou interagindo com funções da STL que usam muito `size_t`. Para garantir que estou utilizando o mesmo tipo e evitar comprarar int e unsigned, por exemplo.

Comment: O código fica cheio de warnings, com a conversão de size_t para int ao usar como indexador. Bizarro isso.

Comment: @Pedro77 ... em principio os warning veem de outro lado, não da indexacão. `size_t index = 42; int arr[100]; arr[index] = 42; /*OK*/` ... mas `arr[index] = index;` gera warning

Comment: @Pedro77 ... ve exemplo em https://gitlab.com/hexkid/stack-overflow/-/raw/main/pt59369.c

Comment: @pmg verdade, mas para indexador no OpenCV não, tenho que botar (int). Nada a ver esse size_t padrão em loop. Não estou convencido.

Comment: @Pedro77 ... aparentemente tropeçamos em mais uma diferença entre C e C++. Tou fora deste debate: nao percebo C++.

Answer (score -6):

size_t é um typedef para unsigned int. Então qualquer situação que couber seu uso, é válido e você pode usar. Claro que observando os limites máximos para a situação.

Historicamente, essa definição foi feita para indexação de vetores, loops bem como para o resultado da utilização do operador sizeof.

Porém, pode ser compreendido como um tipo qualquer e usado sem problema em qualquer situação que for plausível.

Comment: Não há em lugar algum na especificação dizendo que `size_t` é sinônimo de `unsigned int`.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi, [aqui](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h#L206) está a definição, ela se encontra no header stddef.h.

Comment: Não, isso é um detalhe de implementação, e não o que a especificação define. Na especificação, [`std::size_t` deve ser capaz de guardar o tamanho máximo de qualquer objeto de qualquer tipo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (percebe que linhas depois GCC define como `unsigned long`). Em sistemas 32bit, por exemplo, `std::size_t` pode ter 4 bytes (assumindo 1 byte = 8 bits), e em sistemas 64bit, `std::size_t` pode ter 8 bytes. Mas tudo isso é detalhe de implementação, o que realmente é relevante é o que a especificação diz.

Comment: E aqui está o parágrafo relevante: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#3

Comment: Tranquilo, tem a definição mas ele sofre uma ligeira variação dependendo da arquitetura na qual o programa será compilado e executado. A especificação sugere, mas as implementações variam.