# Qual é a finalidade dos comandos size_t e ssize_t em C?

Tags: c, tipagem

Qual a finalidade dos comandos `size_t` e `ssize_t`? Que tipo de dados que eles representam?

```
size_t minhavariavel1;
ssize_t minhavariavel2;
```

Comment: Talvez ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59369/quando-usar-size-t

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quando usar size\_t?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59369/quando-usar-size-t)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tecnicamente não são comandos. São tipos de dados. É verdade que no contexto o tipo está servindo como uma [declaração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) ([*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101)) e isso é traduzido por muita gente como comando.

[`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) essencialmente é o mesmo que um `int` não sinalizado que é usado para armazenar o retorno de uma operação de `sizeof`, mas pode ser diferente em alguma plataforma ou compilador, não é obrigatório ser isso é obrigado ser pelo menos o tamanho de um `int`.

[`ssize_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html) um inteiro sinalizado e é usado em situações que a mesma representação do tamanho de dados que pode retornar um valor negativo, em caso de falha. É fora do padrão ANSI do C, por isso evite seu uso.

Ainda que sejam inteiros, é ideal mantê-los de forma separada. Cada tipo com sua função, dá mais semântica ao dado e evita problemas futuros se precisar fazer alguma mudança.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O int tambem trabalha com valores negativos, porem quando eu quero tratar um erro de uma função que retorna -1 eu utilizo o ssize_t é isso msm?

Comment: Não. Ele é usado para o representar o tamanho de dados. O fato de ser equivalente ao `int` é só uma coincidência.

Answer (score 7):

`size_t` é definido no C padrão (em `stddef.h`). `ssize_t` é a versão *signed* de `size_t`, mas é definido em uma extensão POSIX, portanto pode não existir em todas as plataformas.

O `size_t` representa o tamanho de alguma coisa (quantidade), e como é *unsigned* não representa valores negativos. O `ssize_t`, por ser *signed*, pode também representar tais valores. Por exemplo, o resultado de uma função pode ser o tamanho do parâmetro (se for zero / positivo) ou um código de erro (se for negativo).

Comment: Posso utiliza-los onde eu irei trabalhar somente com valores positivos?

Comment: Nada impede que você use onde quiser mas eu procuro usar size_t apenas para representar tamanhos e unsigned int para valores positivos em geral. Na prática não faz muita diferença mas ajuda na legibilidade.

Comment: Porque você usa unsigned int somente para variáveis com valores positivos?