# Qual a diferença entre uma declaração e uma expressão?

Tags: terminologia, semântica, convenções-de-nome

No universo da programação esses são dois termos bastante usados, mas as vezes vejo pessoas os utilizando (as vezes até profissionais experientes) como se eles fosse intercambiáveis. Isso é válido? Quando cada termo se aplica?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Isso é um pouco complicado porque não compara coisas que parecem comparáveis, já que uma declaração pode ser uma expressão em alguns casos. Vou usar o termo como sendo *statement* porque parece ser uma tradução equivocada apenas e não quer saber sobre a declaração de variáveis e funções e sim sobre um *statement* e uma *expression*.

## Declaração

Declaração no sentido de *statement* costuma ser uma forma imperativa de dizer o que o código deve fazer. A grosso modo é um comando. Ela gera uma "**execução**".

A palavra em português não indica bem o que é. Declaração é uma palavra ambígua e pode ser outra coisa. Pode ser só uma declaração de variáveis, que normalmente é um *statement*, mas nem sempre.

Então declarar uma variável, atribuir valor a ela, dizer que deve tomar uma decisão, que deve desviar o fluxo normal e possivelmente repetir, até mesmo um bloco de código pode ser considerado um *statement* em várias linguagens.

## Expressões

Uma expressão é uma porção de código que gera um valor. Normalmente é composta por outras expressão chamadas subexpressões. É a combinação de um ou mais valores, constantes, variáveis, operadores, e funções que a linguagem interpreta de acordo com certas regras e cria um resultado (é feito um "cálculo") que é um novo valor. O processo que calcula esse valor é chamado de "**avaliação**".

Algumas linguagens especificam que alguns comandos gerem algum resultado e portanto podem ser usados em expressões. Nesse caso o que normalmente é conhecido como *statement* passa ser uma expressão. Então um `if` pode gerar um resultado:

```
x = if a > 0 then 5 else 0 //x valerá 5 ou 0
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/IfExpression.ptg).

É mais ou menos comum as linguagens considerarem que declarações e atribuições de variáveis sejam expressões, portando além de mudar o seu valor, esse valor já é um resultado e pode ser usado em uma expressão.

Uma declaração pode conter expressões, mas expressões não podem conter declarações. No momento que uma declaração passa ser permitida dentro de uma expressão ela passa ser considerada uma expressão.

A maioria das linguagens permitem que expressões sejam usadas como declarações. Por exemplo, chamar uma função é uma expressão, e ela pode ser chamada diretamente sem nada a mais, obviamente o resultado será descartado.

## Diferença

**"Declarações" produzem ações, mas não resultados, como ocorre com expressões**, portanto não podem ser usados como parte de expressões que exigem valores.

Outro ponto secundário comum é que expressões não costumam ter [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101), ou seja, não alteram estados, mas não há uma definição que isso seja proibido em expressões. Declarações podem alterar estados, embora nem todo tipo de declaração precise fazer isso, isso pode ser um pouco diferente em algumas linguagens.

Comment: Agora ficou claro. Obrigado.