# Tipo de retorno de função para uma lista encadeada

Tags: c, funções, lista-encadeada, return

Qual tipo de retorno usar em uma lista encadeada? Por exemplo, em inserir no inicio da lista.

```
void inserir(pessoas **pessoa, int valor)
```

sem retorno (`void`). Ou retornar um ponteiro da lista.

```
pessoas* inserir(pessoas **pessoa, int valor)
```

Qual seria o mais apropriado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro pode ser bem adequado porque provavelmente modifica `pessoa` com o novo elemento e não precisa retornar alguma coisa.

O segundo só é útil se não está alterando a estrutura de dados ou se quer como facilidade deixar a função `inserir()` ser [usada como expressão em algum lugar. A primeira só pode ser usada como *statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101).

Se usar a primeira pode ser útil retornar um verdadeiro ou falso se a operação ocorreu ok. Em alguns cenários pode não conseguir concluí-la e seria interessante [informar que um erro ocorreu de uma forma simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).