# Diferença entre statement e expressão?

Tags: terminologia

Qual a diferença entre um statement e uma expressão no contexto de linguagens de programação?

Poderia mostrar um exemplo de como identico ambos em um trecho de código?

Qual seria o melhor termo ou qual se aproxima mais do conceito em português para statement? instrução?

Comment: Isso `2 + f()` ou `"rray " + "woof"` é uma expressão, e isso `valor = 2 + f();` seria uma declaração (statement) ;)

Comment: Issso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101