# condição ternária ou if e else com PHP

Tags: php, condição

Gostaria de saber, quando devo usar esses tipos de condições, já fiz o teste me retorna a mesma coisa, mas qual a diferença? Acredito que não é só diminuir linhas, mas vamos combinar a segunda opção é mais limpa né?

```
public function method($param) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field = :field";

    $count = $this->_db->select($sql, array('method' => $param[1]));

    if ($count->rowCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Aqui está a segunda com condição ternária.

```
public function method($param) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field = :field";

    $count = $this->_db->select($sql, array('method' => $param[1]));

    return $count->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

O que promove de diferença no meu código?

Comment: Nem precisa do ternário, pode retorna só: `return $count->rowCount() > 0`.

Comment: @rray é que vou usar em outra função, num sistema de vip, se for vip retorna true se não false, true executa uma query, e false executa outra.

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer, que colocando somente `return $count->rowCount() > 0` já vai retorna `true` ou `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse exemplo é a mesma coisa. Sempre que realizar uma única ação o ternário é um bom candidato no lugar do if/else. Caso tenha mais instruções para executar vai precisar o condicional tradicional pois não é possível ter 'N linhas' no ternário.

Pode otimizar seu exemplo assim, pois está testando uma condição e o retorno de uma expressão é sempre booleano logo seu `return` vai ser `true` ou `false`.

```
return $count->rowCount() > 0
```

A tradução da execução seria algo como:

```
return $count->rowCount() > 0
^            ^            ^
3            1            2
```

1 - Executa e obtem o retorno do método `rowCount()`

2 - Testa a expressão por exemplo: `3 > 0`

3 - Descoberta a resposta (booleana) para a expressão do item 2, o `return` em caminha esse valor como retorno do método/função.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Qual a diferença entre uma declaração e uma expressão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/91)

Comment: é funcionou msm jeito então não preciso fazer return `$count->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false;` que simples não? kkkk