# Diferenca entre as 2 expressões?

Tags: java, operadores, expressões

```
int p=4,u=12;

System.out.println(p=u);
System.out.println(p=+u);
```

Não estou a perceber, qual a diferença entre as 2 expressões?

Comment: Vão imprimir o mesmo resultado o primeiro vai atribuir 12 para p, e no segundo caso dá na mesma porque o sinal nesse caso não influencia em nada ( se fosse o sinal de negativo ai influenciava e o valor de p seria -12 na próxima linha)!

Comment: Ter isso ou a variavel multiplicada por -1 (p=u*-1)no caso (p=-u) quer dizer exactamente o mesmo

Comment: Sobrecarga de operador e multiplicação de sinal ,para a maquina é diferente mas o resultado vai ser sempre o mesmo. Mas computacionalmente qual demora mais a ser executado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na teoria é bem diferente. Um faz uma atribuição de uma valor contido em uma variável para outra variável. O outro opera o valor de uma variável afirmando que quer aplicar um positivo nele.

Na prática é a mesma coisa. Quando usa-se o operador de "mais" unário (que é diferente do binário onde faz uma soma), ele é inócuo.

Lembra da aula de matemática? Positivo com positivo dá positivo, positivo com negativo dá negativo, ou seja, nesse caso sempre dará o próprio valor que ele está sendo aplicado.

É certo (duvido que algum compilador funcione diferente) que a linguagem tornará o `+` uma operação nula e na execução não exista uma instrução que faça algo por causa do operador unário, então o desempenho será o mesmo.

Há quem diga que as linguagens nem deveriam ter este operador já que ele não faz algo útil. Há quem diga que ele pode dar uma melhor semântica ao pretendido, mesmo que não mude o resultado.

O operador unário de negativo já influencia, já que se o valor for negativo ele torna-se positivo, conforme a mesma aula de matemática.

Costuma-se não recomendar o uso de algo que tem efeito colateral como [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101). E esse código faz isso. Ele calcula e atribui um valor e já o usa como argumento do método que fará a impressão. Este código seria melhor escrito como:

```
int p = 4, u = 12;
p = u;
System.out.println(p);
p = +u;
System.out.println(p);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/UnaryPlus.java).

Mas depende do contexto. Nesse exemplo nem isso precisaria. Em alguns não vejo problema em usar a atribuição como expressão.

Nem vou entrar na hipótese da pergunta ter um erro de sintaxe e a intenção era fazer outra coisa.

Comment: Mas no caso da atribuição por meio de o sinal negativo (p=-u) o que o compilador faz é multiplicar por -1 o valor de "u" e escreve em p o resultado. Ou a atribuição é feita com base no operador (-). O que eu estou a querer dizer é se a maquina interpreta a expressão (p=-u) e (p=u*-1) da mesma forma

Comment: Isto não está na sua pergunta. O compilador não multiplica nada por -1 em caso algum a não ser que o seu código mande (mesmo isso pode não ser feito pelo compilador).  Não sei o que a última frase quer dizer.

Comment: (p=-u) e (p=u*-1) computacionalmente qual a mais eficiente?

Comment: Depende da implementação. Se não tiver otimização alguma é o primeiro.

Comment: Então na primeira expressão a maquina inverte os bits da variável e escreve o resultado em "p" e na segunda expressão e algo mais complexo computacionalmente?

Comment: Não, depende da implementação, pode fazer de várias formas diferentes. Inclusive o próprio processador pode otimizar algo.

Answer (score 4):

Na primeira impressão existe apenas uma atribuição o `p` recebe o valor de `u`

```
int p=4,u=12;
System.out.println(p=u);
Resultado: 12
```

Na Segunda impressão existe uma atribução porém você faz uso do operador unário `+` sobre o operando `u`:

```
int p=4,u=12;
System.out.println(p=+u); //é o mesmo que p = +(u) OU p = 1(u)
Resultado: 12
```

Com os valores acima fica difícil notar a diferença, mas no exemplo abaixo note a mudança:

```
int p=4,u=-12;
System.out.println(p=-u); //é o mesmo que p = -(u) OU p = -1(u)
Resultado: 12
```

Segue uma pequena explicação sobre operador unário:

```
a = -b;
```

No exemplo acima **b** é o operando sobre o qual o operador **-** age.

Comment: Não diria "indicando o sinal". Pois se `u=-15`, `p` vai valer `-15` após a atribuição. O mais correto seria afirmar que é o uso do operador unário `+`

Comment: O @JeffersonQuesado tirou as palavras do meu teclado. Me avise quando terminar de editar.