# Erro ao criar variável dentro do IF

Tags: php, variáveis, if, declaração-de-variável

Estava criando um script que sempre funcionou comigo, porém, eu fiz uma pequena alteração que quase explodiu a minha mente pois não entendi o que houve e não encontrei nada sobre o tema. É o seguinte:

Esse código funciona perfeitamente:

```
$true1 = true;

if(!$true1 || !($id = true)){
    exit;
}

var_dump($id);
```

Valor retornado **[bool(true)](https://ideone.com/DxgtrL)**

Porém, quando eu altero `||` por `&&` gera um erro de variável não definida:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /home/vHrTJp/prog.php on line
>   11

```
$true1 = true;

if(!$true1 && !($id = true)){
    exit;
}

var_dump($id);
```

Retornando o valor **[NULL](https://ideone.com/fH48sn)**

Isso também funciona:

```
if(!($id = true)){
    exit;
}

var_dump($id); // bool(true)
```

**Como isso é possível?**

Nenhuma das condições acima deveria retornar um erro.. certo? Ou não?

Comment: errei o comentário, disfarça

Comment: @EvertonNeri nem cheguei a ler. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos analisar o código que interessa:

```
!$true1 && !($id = true)
```

A primeira expressão a ser avaliada é a negação da variável `$true1`. O resultado dá falso. Como em seguida vem um operador de `&&` que obriga que ambos os operandos sejam `true` para que o resultado final seja `true`. Pois bem, ele já sabe que de um lado é falso, então é impossível a expressão toda ser `true`. Por que ele perderia tempo tentando avaliar a segunda parte da expressão (`!($id = true)`) se ela se torna irrelevante? Ela não sendo executada e a variável `$id` nunca é criada, e quando mandar imprimi-la obviamente dá erro.

A falha do PHP aí é deixar que uma variável possa ou não ser criada condicionalmente. É um erro da linguagem, mas sabendo disso você tem que seguir esta regra.

Pra completeza de explicação a expressão

```
$true1 || !($id = true)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Boolean.php).

também daria o mesmo erro. O primeiro dá `true`, e no caso do `||` basta um deles ser `true`, então ele já sabe que o todo será verdadeiro, portanto não tem porque avaliar a segunda parte.

No caso do exemplo deu certo porque a primeira parte dá falso, então é necessário avaliar a segunda parte para ter certeza se dará falso ou poderá ser verdadeiro.

Isso chama-se [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101).

O último código obviamente funciona porque a expressão é única e sempre será avaliada, portanto a variável é criada.

De qualquer forma evite criar variáveis como expressão. Até atribuir um valor para uma variável dentro de uma expressão não é um grande problema, embora recomenda-se usar com cuidado, criar deveria até ser proibido pela linguagem, mas em PHP não é. Só crie variáveis como [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101). Mas se for criar, aí tome o cuidado de testar antes de usar a variável que pode ter sido criada ou não.

Curiosamente tem linguagem, como o C#, que permite criar a variável condicionalmente, mas como foi proposital e não um acidente, ela só deixa usar a variável dentro da condição sendo verdadeira.

Comment: Interessante! Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Se é falsa não tem como entrar no `if`.

Comment: kkk verdade. Já estou cansado. O dia inteiro no PC. kkkk