# Union e struct podem ser consideradas operadores?

Tags: c, struct, operadores, union

Uma `union` ou uma `struct` podem ser consideradas operadores? Assim como `return`, `goto` e [`sizeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-language/sizeof-operator-c?view=vs-2017)?

Answer (score 5):

Não podem, assim como não podem `return` e `goto`. Só o `sizeof` aí é um operador, e mesmo assim ele tem um jeito especial, porque ele sempre é executado em tempo de compilação. Não é a toa que o único que pode *linkar* como operador. Então a pergunta parte de premissa errada.

Esses são comandos *statements* da linguagem, são palavras reservadas, como o `sizeof`.

`union` e `struct` são *statements* também, mas eles têm uma função mais declarativa, eles não são exatamente imperativos como os anteriores. Eles determinam que ali terá uma declaração de uma estrutura de dados de união ou de estrutura composta de dados. Eles declaram tipos novos para seu código. Portanto não são operadores.

Operadores tem por função manipular (acessar) dados e resultar em alguma coisa, são expressões.

Mais:

- [O que são statements e operadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma declaração e uma expressão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).