# O que são statements e operadores?

Tags: .net, terminologia, operadores, independente-de-linguagem

Costumo acessar o [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us) com frequência e vejo bastante esses termos.

O que são *statements* e operadores? O que os diferencia?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Statement

[*Statement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)) é uma declaração, pela tradução literal. É uma afirmação. Muitas vezes chamamos em português de comando, ainda que a palavra não expresse bem o que é. Normalmente usado em linguagens imperativas (quase todas *mainstream*) e é todo o necessário para completar uma instrução completa para o computador executar.

Em geral ele executa aquilo e encerra. Ele não produz um resultado (um valor que aquilo determina, mas sim uma ação, ele faz algo, ao contrário de produzir algo para ser usado posteriormente. Nesse ponto é o oposto de uma expressão.

Em geral há uma sequência deles e costuma começar por uma palavra-chave que diz o que está mandando fazer. Mas há exceções. Em alguns casos uma expressão pode funcionar como um *statement*. É o caso de atribuições de variáveis, ou até a declaração inicial dela, ou chamadas de função isoladamente.

Um *statement* pode ser composto por vários outros formando um bloco.

É comum, se não for um bloco, mas em muitas linguagens não obrigatório, que ele ocupe uma linha. Em linguagens da linhagem do C (C#, por exemplo) o `;` indica o fim do *statement* e as chaves indicam o início e fim de um bloco de *statements*. Então pode ter mais de um *statement* na mesma linha, ou o mesmo *statement* ser dividido em várias linhas.

Em outras linguagens (VB.NET, por exemplo), o caractere de nova linha indica seu fim, podendo que [colocar mais que na mesma linha com `:` ou pode quebrá-lo em mais de uma linha com `_`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Note que as linguagens costumam permitir *statements* vazios. Em C#, por exemplo um `;` sozinho é um *statement* válido que faz nada. Isso pode ser bastante observado em um `for` quando se omite alguma das partes que ele é composto. Veja um *loop* infinito:

```
for (;;)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/InfiniteLoop.cs).

Aí existem três *statements*, mesmo que não tenha nada neles. Mesmo o último conta também, o fechamento dos parênteses encerra o *statement*.

Um detalhe importante que muita gente confunde é que o *statement* não é a palavra-chave que geralmente inicia um *statement*. Ele é o conjunto de coisas que manda fazer alguma coisa em uma instrução. Existem *statements* sem palavra-chave, como a atribuição de variáveis, chamada de função ou procedimento sem mais nada, entre outros.

Já respondi por cima em [Qual a diferença entre uma declaração e uma expressão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101).

## Operador

[Operador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)) é uma forma análoga ao que encontramos em matemática. Ele funciona como se fossem funções (alguns de fato por baixo dos panos são mesmo em certas linguagens e contextos). Eles costumam formar expressões junto com seus operandos, sempre produzindo um resultado, como ocorre com toda [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163079/101).

Algumas linguagens preferem símbolos, sempre que possível próximos ao que se usa em matemática, mas nem sempre. Outras preferem palavras descrevendo-os. E há as que misturam entre essas duas formas, o mais comum. Então você pode ter um `&&` e um `AND` que possuem sintaxe diferente em linguagens diferentes e semântica idêntica ou muito próxima.

Você tem operadores como `is`, `typeof`, `sizeof`, `new`, entre outros, que são operadores, mas muita gente acha que são funções, principalmente quando eles costumam ser usados com parênteses. Por isso que eu acho importante deixar os parênteses colados no nome da função e separados quando servem apenas como agrupamento de sub-expressões. Tem gente que acha isso bobagem ou só gosto, mas é útil visualmente para passar uma mensagem. É mais [elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/101).

Até o ponto que separa o objeto de seu membro é um operador (`obj.propriedade`), e muita gente não percebe. A atribuição é um operador (`i++`, `x *= 2`, `a = b - 3` que é uma expressão e um *statement* ao mesmo tempo na maioria das linguagens).

Em geral operadores possuem regras de [precedência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) e [associatividade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) ([exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)).

Algumas linguagens permitem definir comportamento de alguns operadores para seus tipos, ou até mesmo criar novos operadores.

É comum os operadores terem uma notação *infix* (ela está no meio de dois operandos), mas também pode ser *prefix* (vai antes do operando único), ou pode ser *postfix* (vai depois do operando). Alguns podem ser operadores diferentes dependendo de onde é colocado, caso típico do pré e pós-incremento/decremento.

É comum existir pelo menos um operador com três operandos, por isso ele é chamado de ternário (mas de fato o que existe é um condicional. Ele é ternário, mas vários operadores são unários ou binários, conforme falei acima. Como costuma existir apenas um ternário há essa confusão.

Um operador é um [*token*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_(parser)) único.

## Conclusão

Digamos que eles não possuem relação direta a não ser que operadores podem ser usados em expressões e essas podem estar em *statements*.