# Erro na compilação: expected ';' before 'case'

Tags: c++, switch

Estou tentando compilar esse programa aqui no Code::Blocks mas não estou conseguindo e não estou entendendo o por quê.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main()
 
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Qual o mês atual Digite apenas um número de 0 a 12" <<  endl;
    cin >> x ;
    switch (x)
 {
     case 1 : cout << "Janeiro" << endl; break
     case 2 : cout << "Fevereiro" << endl; break
     case 3 : cout << "Março" << endl; break
     case 4 : cout << "Abril" << endl; break
     case 5 : cout << "Maio" << endl; break
     case 6 : cout << "Junho" << endl; break
     case 7 : cout << "Julho" << endl; break
     case 8 : cout << "Agosto" << endl; break
     case 9 : cout << "Setembro" << endl; break
     case 10 : cout << "Outubro" << endl; break
     case 11 : cout << "Novembro" << endl; break
     case 12 : cout << "Dezembro" << endl; break
     default : cout << "Digite um número de 0 à 12" << endl;
     }
 
 
}
```

[image: Código].

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

O compilador mostrou qual é o erro, bastava ler e consertar isso. Falta o `;` após cada `break` para encerrar o [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101). Talvez se não tivesse colocado tudo na mesma linha isso ficasse mais claro.

Eu dei uma organizada melhor no código. Códigos mais legíveis são mais fáceis de achar erros.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Qual o mês atual Digite apenas um número de 0 a 12" << endl;
    cin >> x ;
    switch (x) {
        case 1 : cout << "Janeiro" << endl; break;
        case 2 : cout << "Fevereiro" << endl; break;
        case 3 : cout << "Março" << endl; break;
        case 4 : cout << "Abril" << endl; break;
        case 5 : cout << "Maio" << endl; break;
        case 6 : cout << "Junho" << endl; break;
        case 7 : cout << "Julho" << endl; break;
        case 8 : cout << "Agosto" << endl; break;
        case 9 : cout << "Setembro" << endl; break;
        case 10 : cout << "Outubro" << endl; break;
        case 11 : cout << "Novembro" << endl; break;
        case 12 : cout << "Dezembro" << endl; break;
        default : cout << "Digite um número de 0 à 12" << endl;
     }
 }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WSQjbC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xawxwxdp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/PrintMonth.cpp).

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Colega, se a resposta te ajudou, por favor considere [marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Além de ajudar o sistema a funcionar melhor, essa é a forma mais apropriada de agradecer à quem te ajudou. :)