# Por que o retorno em um método de operador de atribuição?

Tags: c++, memória, operadores, sobrecarga

Estou apreendendo sobre operadores de sobrecarga, mas não entendi porque o retorno no final do método. Não bastaria apenas criar nova alocação de memória?

```
StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & st)

{

    cout<<"**********USANDO O OPERADOR************";

if (this == &st)    // object assigned to itself

return *this;   // all done

delete [] str;  // free old string

len = st.len;

str = new char [len + 1];   // get space for new string

std::strcpy(str, st.str);   // copy the string

return *this;   // return reference to invoking object

}
```

Esta é a `main()`:

```
StringBad headline1("Celery Stalks at Midnight");
StringBad knot;

knot =(headline1);

cout << "knot: " << knot << endl;

cout << "Exiting the block.\n";

cout << "End of main()\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, porque os operadores são expressões e expressões sempre devem gerar um resultado para ser usado onde ele está escrito, e um resultado é gerado com um `return`.

Se ele fosse só [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) não precisaria, mas a linguagem não especificou assim. Isto é um *statement*:

```
knot = headline1;
```

Isto é uma expressão `knot = headline1`. Usando em código pode-se perceber melhor:

```
cout << "knot: " << knot = headline1 << endl;
```

Desta forma você está atribuindo algo a `knot` e usando isto como argumento em `cout`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/ReturnReference.cpp).

Comment: entao o retorno  é uma regras nesse caso é obrigatório

Comment: Sim, de acordo com a especificação da linguagem.

Comment: OK OBRIGADO DE NOVO !!! VC É UMA FERA OBRIGADO MESMO

Comment: @dougllas você já pode votar em tudo no site, veja o [tour].