# Como eu posso chamar um método void da classe para mostrar uma mensagem em um formulário?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, método, return

Tenho um método `public void listarProduto()`. Ele precisa ter todas as informações de entrada pelo usuário. O meu problema está na hora de chamar esse método dentro de um `MessageBox()` no formulário para que a mensagem seja exibida.

Comment: Se você estiver tentando acessar o método sem uma instância, coloque public static void listarProduto() e veja se funciona

Comment: obrigatoriamente tem que ser void ?

Comment: Void define que o método não tem retorno. Você quer retornar algo ? um int ? uma string ?

Comment: Mostre o seu código, e alertando métodos `void` não tem retorno.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Comment: Você pode postar o código do que você está tentando fazer? Porque você quer chamar um método `void` dentro de um `MessageBox`? Porque não chamá-lo antes ou depois?

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, pelo menos se entendi a colocação. Se o método faz algo mas não resulta em nada ele não pode ser usado como expressão em um lugar que espera alguma informação, método de retorno `void` só podem ser chamados como [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101).

Ou deve modificar o método para retornar o que deseja usar no `MessageBox()` ou deve pegar outra informação em algum lugar se ela estiver disponível.

Provavelmente há um erro neste método, porque se ele lista alguma coisa mesmo, ou seja, se é algo de tela, ele já faz o que deveria e não precisa passar isso para o `MessageBox()`, provavelmente deveria ter um `MessageBox() dentro dele mostrando o que deseja.

Por outro lado o mais provável é que ele só entregue os dados do produto para fazer o que deseja, aí deveria retornar um objeto ou uma *string*, ou seja, ele não deveria tratar da tela, são responsabilidades diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que você tá falando, acho que seria o contrário, o jeito seria chamar o método e executar a chamada do `MessageBox()` dentro desse método.