# Isto é válido (x = (*mat)++;)?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, sintaxe

```
(x = (*mat)++;)
```

Se for válido, me expliquem porque e como vai funcionar.

Comment: Esta se referindo ao ponto e virgula (`;`)?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Isso não é válido, você não pode ter um [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) dentro de parênteses. Por que?

Porque a [especificação da linguagem (texto antigo, os novos são pagos)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) diz assim. Poderiam permitir, mas não há vantagem nisto e eventualmente algo poderia conflitar com a evolução da linguagem.

A ideia é não deixar fazer maluquices. Sem os parênteses externos e com o devido código em volta seria válido. De qualquer forma, analisar um código isolado assim faz pouco sentido.

Quando quer saber se algo é válido, escreva em um arquivo e veja se o compilador aceita.

Comment: Obrigado, ficou bastante claro agora!

Comment: @JrFelix dê uma olhada no [tour] para ver a melhor forma de agradecer.

Comment: Vc postou uma especificação de quase 1400 páginas. Onde que diz que isso é inválido?

Comment: @Amadeus sei lá, mas se os compiladores invalidam isto deve estar na especificação, afinal o que não está nela não tem porque fazer algo assim no compilador :)

Comment: @Amadeus capítulo 6 dá a gramática de statements. Não recordo em nenhum outro canto onde é especificado a possibilidade de se ter ;