# Dúvida entre bloco e declaração

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

Nessa pergunta, qual seria resposta certa?

> How many statements are there in the code below? Warning: This is a
>   tricky one. The code is valid.
>
> ```
> { println("Step 2");
>   { println("Step 2a");
>     { println("Step 2a.1");
>   { }
>     }   
>   }
> }
>
> a.1
> b.3
> c.4
> d.7
> e.None of the above
> ```

Eu acredito que seja a C, pois um bloco é uma declaração. Entretanto pode ser D também. Qual é a correta?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente respondi genericamente e pesquisando por cima havia documentação que dava a entender que um bloco não é um *statement*.

Vendo a especificação do Java fica claro que a resposta certa é a D, há 7 *statements*. São 4 blocos que são considerados *statements* pela linguagem e os 3 comandos que mandam imprimir alguma coisa.

De fato na [seção 14.5 da especificação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block) a gramática mostra que o bloco por si só é um *statement*. Fora essa parte não fica tão claro que isso seja verdade.

Veja [O que são statements e operadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101).

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na Java Language Specification [14.5 Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) e capítulos vinculados - aqui somente as partes importantes (IMHO):

> ```
> Statement:
>     StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>
> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>     Block
>     ExpressionStatement
>
> Block:
>      { [BlockStatements] } 
>
> BlockStatements:
>     BlockStatement {BlockStatement} 
>
> BlockStatement:
>     Statement
>
> ExpressionStatement:
>     StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>     MethodInvocation
> ```

Entâo o bloco, vazio ou nâo, conta como um Statement (pela JLS) e, obviamente, cada `println` também é um Statement (`MethodInvocation`).