# Interpretação de laço de repetição

Tags: php, for, sintaxe

Estou com dificuldades para entender o seguinte código que é apresentado como exercício de um livro.

```
$a = true;
$b = -2;
$c = 7;

for ( ; $b < $c || $a; $b++){
    if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        $a = false;
        echo $b." ";
}
```

O resultado é: -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Porque o primeiro parâmetro do `for` não é passado ? Eu preciso de uma explicação completa, pois não consigo assimilar o código com o resultado.

Comment: A variável `$b` já está declarada, então seria o mesmo que `for($b = -2; $b < $c || $a; $b++)`

Comment: Tem outras partes deste código ou é só isto? Muda tudo se tiver outras partes.

Comment: é só isso. Mas pq o ponto é virgula no início do for ? se ue remover retorna um erro

Comment: Mas o problema não era o primeiro *statement* do `for`? Você trocou a aceitação para uma resposta que nem toca no assunto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A narrativa seria, b começa a execução com -2, e enquanto b for menor que c, que neste caso vale 7, ou a for verdadeiro (true), o código de dentro do laço de repetição é executado, testando a seguinte condição: se b que vale -2 * 2 + c que vale 7 é maior que 20, redefine o estado de a para falso (false), e mostra na tela o valor de b concatenado a um espaço vazio.
Para cada volta no laço, b passa a valer ele mesmo + 1, alterando seu valor, o teste é refeito até que a condição do laço não seja satisfeita, seja pelo teste de b < c ou a sendo true. Pelo menos uma das duas condições precisam ser obrigatoriamente verdadeiras para que o loop aconteça.

```
$a = true; // Valor inicial de desta variável.
$b = -2; // Valor inicial de desta variável.
$c = 7; // Valor inicial de desta variável.

// Para cada vez que a repetição contatar que b realmente é menir que c ou a for verdadeiro, executa o código identado após arepetição e acrescenta mais 1 unidade ao valor de b.
for ( ; $b < $c || $a; $b++){
    // Todas as vezes que as condições acima forem satisfeitas, é realizada uma multiplicação, depois uma adição, e por fim, testado se seu valor é mair do que 20.
    if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        // Caso as condições acima sejam satisfeitas, o estado de a é modificado para false, e é mostrado na tela o valor de b.
        $a = false;
        echo $b." ";

    // Por fim o loop adiciona uma unidade ao valor de b, conforme citado anteriormente, e o loop volta ao inicio para um novo teste.
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta está certa, apenas essa parte... "As duas condições precisam ser obrigatoriamente verdadeiras para que o loop aconteça."... Na verdade não. Na verdade UMA das condições precisam ser obrigatoriamente 
 verdadeira para que o loop aconteça.

Comment: Então essa parte teria que ficar assim ".. o teste é refeito até que (nenhuma) (d)a(s) condição(ões) do laço não seja(m) satisfeita(s) TANTO pelo teste de b < c E a sendo true..."

Comment: `||` é `E` ou `OU`?

Comment: Pois é, eu tinha vacilado, mais já fiz a correção na resposta.

Answer (score 10):

É um código bastante confuso e não sei se é bom para tentar entender se ainda lhe falta conhecimento básico de como a sintaxe funciona.

O `for` não tem parâmetros, ele tem 3 [*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101), ou declarações a serem feitas: a inicialização de uma variável, a condição de parada dele, e o passo, geralmente um incremento. Se ele espera 3 tem que colocar os 3, mesmo que um deles fique em branco, não pode remover o `;` porque aí ficaria 2.

Se não precisa inicializar ali alguma variável não tem porque colocar algo, então deixa-se em branco. Raramente isto faz sentido. Se inicializar a variável só existirá dentro do `for`, mas como neste caso não tem mais nada pode inicializar `$b` ali mesmo.

`$c` não varia então não vejo sentido manter esta variável. Nada útil é feito com `$a`, então é só eliminá-la também.

O código todo tem um problema de legibilidade, assim fica melhor e produz o mesmo resultado:

```
for ($b = -2; $b < 7; $b++) echo $b . " ";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/SimpleLoop.php).

Comment: Aah deu pra assimilar a situação agora. Realmente não faz muito sentido este código. Porém a intenção do livro é deixar o raciocínio mais articulado para a programação, por isso a maiorias dos exercícios são um pouco exagerado. Mas consegui entender bem agora. Vlw pela força. Abraço

Comment: Por isso considero esta uma fonte ruim, cria vícios, deturpa o pensamento, deveria procurar algo que faz coisas que tenham sentido.

Comment: Eu sempre comento quando dou voto negativo. O AP não pediu melhorias ou uma forma melhor de realizar a tarefa, ele só queria entender a lógica do exercício que foi dado, coisa que vc não fez na sua resposta.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu respondi o que estava na pergunta que era o que faz o primeiro "parâmetro* em branco, e mostrei que não precisava estar em branco. E não se esquece que eu sou moderador e sei que não comenta em tudo o que negativa, mas tudo bem não é obrigado fazê-lo. tem algo errado na resposta? Eu ensinei errado? Não respondi o que estritamente foi perguntado? É um direito seu usar o critério que quiser, mas a resposta não está errada para receber um negativo. Ensina algo útil, e melhor, **além** de ter respondido o que foi perguntado. Usando seu critério devo negativar a sua por colocar JS

Comment: `Eu preciso de uma explicação completa, pois não consigo assimilar o código com o resultado.`

Comment: Vamos ignorar o fato de o autor da pergunta ter dito "Aah deu pra assimilar a situação agora." já no primeiro comentário, que é pra justificar essa conversa estar ocorrendo :D

Comment: Hummm, joguei um verde e colhi maduro, quer dizer que moderador sabe quem  negativa. Ouvi dizer de um graduado uma vez que nem moderador sabe quem negativa. O episódio ocorreu porque alguém estava achando que era perseguido por algum fulano que dava constantemente voto negativo nas respostas dele.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não é bem assim, dá pra saber "quem negativa e não comenta" como ele mesmo disse, por que existem as estatísticas gerais. Só CM pode ver voto individual (isso já foi bem debatido no chat oficial, pode dar uma pesquisada por lá). Muito disso até a gente que não tem poderes especiais sabe. Basta ver o número de negativos no perfil da pessoa, e o tanto que ela comenta.

Comment: Por exemplo, tinha usuário usando indevidamente os comentários da rede como spam para campanha de moderador (o que mostra com que tipo de pessoas estamos lidando), provavelmente essa pessoa não sabe que todos vemos o histórico, mas ele existe. Muitas vezes o desconhecimento da ferramenta leva a conclusões precipitadas, ou a se achar que determinadas pessoas tem mais privilégios que outras.

Answer (score 5):

> Após as devidas explicações e funcionamento do loop FOR, tanto em javascript quanto no PHP (para ressaltar a semelhança dos dois), veja no final desta resposta, seu código comentado e rodando `passo a passo` no ideone.

A instrução for cria um loop que consiste em três expressões opcionais, dentro de parênteses e separadas por ponto e vírgula, seguidas por uma declaração ou uma sequência de declarações executadas em sequência.

```
for ([inicialização]; [condição]; [expressão final])
```

**inicialização**

Uma expressão (incluindo expressões de atribuição) ou declarações variáveis. Geralmente usada para iniciar o contador de variáveis. Esta expressão pode, opcionalmente, declarar novas variáveis com a palavra chave var. Essas variáveis são não locais no loop, isto é, elas estão no mesmo escopo que o loop for está. O resultado desta expressão é descartado.

**condição**

Uma expressão para ser avaliada antes de cada iteração do loop. Se esta expressão for avaliada para true, statement será executado. Este teste da condição é opcional. Se omitido, a condição sempre será avaliada como verdadeira. Se a expressão for avaliada como falsa, a execução irá para a primeira expressão após a construção loop for.
expressão final
Uma expressão que será avaliada no final de cada iteração de loop. Isso ocorre antes da próxima avaliação da condição. Geralmente usado para atualizar ou incrementar a variável do contador.

**declaração**

Uma declaração que é executada enquanto a condição for verdadeira. Para executar múltiplas condições dentro do loop, use uma instrução de bloco ({...}) para agrupar essas condições. Para não executar declarações dentro do loop, use uma instrução vazia (;).

**Exemplos de uso**

A declaração for começa declarando a variável i e inicializando-a como 0. Ela verifica se i é menor que nove, executa as duas instruções subsequentes e incrementa 1 a variável i após cada passagem pelo loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

### Todas as três expressões na condição do loop for são opcionais.

Por exemplo, no bloco de inicialização, não é necessário inicializar variáveis:

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < 9; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Assim como ocorre no bloco de inicialização, a condição também é opcional. Se você está omitindo essa expressão, você deve certificar-se de quebrar o loop no corpo para não criar um loop infinito.

```
for (var i = 0;; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   if (i > 3) break;
}
```

Você também pode omitir todos os três blocos. Novamente, certifique-se de usar uma instrução break no final do loop e também modificar (incrementar) uma variável, paa que a condição do break seja verdadeira em algum momento.

```
var i = 0;

for (;;) {
  if (i > 3) break;
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

[**FONTE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

### Com PHP É bem semelhante, veja

**Exemplos de uso**

A declaração for começa declarando a variável i e inicializando-a como 0. Ela verifica se i é menor que nove, executa as duas instruções subsequentes e incrementa 1 a variável i após cada passagem pelo loop.

Nesse primeiro exemplo temos nosso FOR comum, como todos aprendemos:

```
 <?php

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
            echo $i;
            echo '<br />';
    }
```

Nesse segundo exemplo, retiramos o primeiro parâmetro do FOR, e deixamos a variável $i definida fora do laço:

```
 <?php

    $i = 0;

    for(; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
            echo $i;
            echo '<br />';
    }
```

Agora, vamos tirar o terceiro parâmetro, e incrementar a variável dentro do laço.

```
<?php

    $i = 0;

    for(; $i < 5;)
    {
            echo $i;
            echo '<br />';
            $i++;
    }
```

Por último, vamos retirar o segundo parâmetro.

```
<?php

    $i = 0;

    for(; ; )
    {
            echo $i;
            echo '<br />';

            if($i == 5)
            {
                    break;
            }

            $i++;
    }
```

Quer ver para crer? [**teste de São Tomé no ideone**](https://ideone.com/QAvgW0)

Repare que em todos esses exemplos acima, fugimos do Loop infinito com alguma condição ou mecanismo que colocamos dentro do laço. Tome cuidado. Esse último exemplo se não for feito nada dentro do laço, gera facilmente um Loop infinito.

### Seu código comentado

```
$a = true;
$b = -2;
$c = 7;
$condicao="";


//realiza uma iteração FOR toda vez que $b for menor que $c ou $a for true
//retiramos o primeiro parâmetro do FOR, a variável $b já foi definida fora do laço
for ( ; $b < $c || $a; $b++){

        if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        // quando a condição acima for verdadeira, $a se torna false
        $a = false;
        //e a condição FOR já não será mais verdadeira, isto é, zefini, ou seja, "c'est fini"
        echo $b."  ";

}
```

### Acompanhe o passo a passo do seu código no  [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Xn88HP)

Comment: No caso dele a linguagem é *PHP* boa parte se aplica e partes não.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, kkk, nem tinha percebido a tag

Answer (score 3):

Como dito nos comentários: "*A variável `$b` já está declarada*"

O formato tradicional do loop `for` é:

```
for (
    $i=0; //Declaração de variável
    $i < 10; //Condição para que o loop continue
    $i++ //Ação a cada interação, no caso incremento
) {
}
```

No seu:

```
//Declaração das variáveis
$a = true;
$b = -2;
$c = 7;

for (
    ; //Não há uma declaração porque ela já foi feita antes
    $b < $c || $a; //Duas condição para continuar o loop, que $b seja menor que $c e $a seja veridadeiro
    $b++ //Incrementa o valor de $b para continuar as iterações
) {
    if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        $a = false;
    echo $b." ";
}
```

É importante adicionar o primeiro ponto e vírgula (`;`) porque, sem ele, é como estivesse faltando uma parte do código, o PHP não divide por conta própria essas partes

Esse código também poderia ser escrito assim:

```
for (
    $a = true, $b = -2, $c = 7; //Muda as declarações de lugar
    $b < $c || $a; //Duas condição para continuar o loop, que $b seja menor que $c e $a seja veridadeiro
    $b++ //Incrementa o valor de $b para continuar as iterações
) {
    if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        $a = false;
    echo $b." ";
}
```

Ou ainda com outro tipo de loop:

```
$a = true;
$b = -2;
$c = 7;

while ($b < $c || $a){
    if ($c + $b * 2 > 20)
        $a = false;
    echo $b++." ";
    //O incremento poderia ser numa linha separada mas para reduzir deixei assim
}
```

Observação:

- As quebras de linha dentro do `for` é apenas para aumentar a legibilidade
- Cuidado identar, seu `echo` tem um `tab` a mais, dando a impressão que ele só será executado caso a condição `if` seja verdadeira, o que não é o caso. Sem as chaves (`{ }`) apenas o comando seguinte do `if` estará "dentro dele"