# Padrão de código para chamada de funções

Tags: funções, estilo-de-codificação

Não me recordo bem onde, mas acho que foi em alguma discussão em um tópico aqui no SO mesmo, referente a que na declaração de `if`, ou qualquer outra função da própria linguagem deve ser chamada com um espaço após o nome, ex.:

```
if ()
foreach ()
```

E funções criadas no próprio projeto devem ser chamadas sem esse espaço.

Por acaso há alguma metodologia de boas práticas que determine essa regra? Como um *CamelCase* da vida?

Comment: Sinceramente não estou entendendo os downvotes, acredito que a pergunta esteja dentro do escopo do fórum (?), é especificamente sobre algum padrão de programação do qual queria confirmar se realmente existe, pois não consegui encontrar uma terminologia referente a isso.

Comment: Estilo de codificação padronizado depende muito de que linguagem você está usando e da comunidade dela.

Comment: @fernandosavio sim, eu compreendo. É que minha dúvida era especificamente sobre essa diferenciação de espaçamento após os statements e funções, mas agradeço a colaboração!

Comment: Ah bom, realmente, nunca vi uma padronização que separasse os parênteses da chamada de função.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos definir bem os termos. Chamaremos de função o que é da biblioteca ou criado por você. O que está falando na pergunta (`if` e `foreach`) são palavras chave reservadas da linguagem. Não é uma função e é preciso entender bem isto.

Embora as linguagens sejam liberais com o uso do espaço em branco antes do parênteses é interessante para dar mais legibilidade que os use de forma adequada, e principalmente consistente.

Em uma função é mais comum as pessoas optarem por não colocar um espaço em branco antes da abertura dos parênteses. Assim:

```
SomaProdutos(lista)
```

Ou na declaração da função:

```
int SomaProdutos(Array lista) { ... }
```

Nada impede fazer:

```
SomaProdutos (lista)
```

Mas isso dá uma impressão que não é uma função. Parece um nome e um conjunto de informações agrupadas com parênteses. Ainda que não seja, batendo o olho rapidamente dá um rápida dúvida no cérebro.

Já os [*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) não são funções e se você não coloca o espaço fica parecendo que é uma. Note que esses *statements* que envolvem uma condição ou algum argumento extra costumam, na maioria das linguagens, estar dentro de parênteses para evitar ambiguidade sintática, mas isso não quer dizer que é o mesmo que uma função. Então separado fica mais claro que não é uma função, algo assim:

```
if (x == 1)
    for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) { ... }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Space.cs).

Não muda nada se tirar o espaço, mas por um curto instante você não sabe se é uma função ou não dependendo de como seu olho passa por esse texto.

Não é uma regra, mas questão de organização. Quem tem relaxo ao não se preocupar com isso não se preocupa com outras coisas. o cérebro não tem uma chavinha que liga e desliga o relaxo. Não é o fim do mundo fazer do jeito ruim, mas não é o melhor e não custa nada fazer bem feito. Tem IDEs que até já formatam do jeito escolhido.

Mas o pior é a pessoas usarem o espaço ou não conforme o momento. Trocar o padrão aleatoriamente é pior que usar um padrão ruim. E um padrão que poucos programadores usam, ou pelo menos poucos bons, é algo ruim. É melhor a pessoa programar como a maioria o faz, assim facilita a comunicação.

Que bom que está preocupado até com o espaço em branco. Use espaços horizontais suficientes para dar legibilidade, mas não coloque nos locais onde pode dar impressão errada.

Eu tenho uma opinião mais polêmica (não deveria ser) sobre espaços verticais. Afinal se precisa separar um bloco vertical o código está complexo demais para ficar em apenas uma função, ou então a pessoa separa o que não deveria, quebrando o fluxo de leitura, mas como a maioria segue o que os outros fazem sem pensar naquilo virou padrão espaçar verticalmente. Há casos que a pessoa nem sabe porque está pulando uma linha.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado, era exatamente esse tipo de explicação que estava procurando.