# Como Python identifica quais comandos estão dentro do if?

Tags: python, sintaxe

Em C temos como informar o tamanho, ou até onde a função esta presente como por exemplo:

```c
if (n > 2){ ... }
```

mas em Python é

```py
if n > 2: ...
```

Eu gostaria de entender até onde essas funções terminam pois em C temos chaves para visualizar mas em Python não, quando preciso criar um `if`, ou for não sei até onde o if esta atuando para criar outra função.

Comment: Em uma linha: **IDENTAÇAO**

Comment: O "abrir e fechar" de blocos é feito através de identação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Em C temos como informar o tamanho, ou até onde a função esta presente

Esta afirmação está errada. Isso nada tema ver com função isto é um bloco de comandos. Uma função sempre tem um bloco de comandos. Algumas comandos podem ou não ter um bloco de comandos. Então isto é valido:

```
if (n > 2) ...
```

ou

```
if (n > 2)
    ....
```

Desde que seja apenas um [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101). Se tiver mais que um aí as chaves devem ser usadas para agrupar os comandos como um bloco único, em C. Algumas pessoas preferem sempre usar o bloco mesmo quando tem apenas um *statement* por padronização. Eu testei ambos em cada linguagem, fico um cima do muro em alguns casos.

Não importa se tem uma linha ou mais, a quantidade de linhas não define nada em C, mas se tiver várias haverá confusão e pode parecer algo errado. Inclusive indentação não importa para essa linguagem, então isso não faz o que você imagina (só a primeira linha é condicional):

```
if (n > 2)
    printf("%d", n);
    n++
```

Python usa uma técnica chamada *whitespace significancy*, então quando você faz um espaçamento chamado indentação é como se estivesse iniciando um bloco de comandos, é como se estivesse abrindo a chave (*indent*) e quando volta alguns espaços em uma linha para a mesma coluna que estava o cabeçalho desse bloco é como se tivesse fechando a chave (*dedent*).

Em Python linhas se confundem com *statements* em muitos casos.

Como há alguma ambiguidade para o autor é comum precisar colocar `:` no fim do comando que poderá ter um bloco. O compilador não precisa disto e acho que foi exagero exigir isto (a linguagem tem a filosofia de ser explícita prioritariamente, mas nem sempre segue, afinal o uso das chaves é a forma mais explícita e não ambígua de fazer isto, é até a crítica mais forte do não uso de chaves em Python ou C).

Então é válido (uma linha):

```
if n > 2: print(n)
print()
```

Ou assim:

```
if n > 2:
    print(n)
n += 1 #não é condicional
print()
```

Que fazem a mesma coisa. Já:

```
if n > 2:
    print()
    n += 1 #condicional
print()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/IfBlock.py).

Já aí as duas linhas indentadas fazem parte do mesmo bloco e são condicionais.

O primeiro não tem um bloco claro, então encerra ali na linha mesmo, e sabemos que não tem um bloco porque não teve indentação.

O segundo é a indentação que determinou o início e fim do bloco de comandos, no caso só tendo um comando.

E o terceiro a indentação determinou um bloco de dois *statements*.

Python preferiu adotar oficialmente o que é apenas convencionado usar em C para melhor organizar. Eu gosto disso, muita gente não gosta. Tem vantagens e desvantagens. Em C deixa funcionar com indentação toda errada, em Python não (até certo ponto). Python tende a tornar o código mais limpo, mas quem é desorganizado faz códigos ruins do mesmo jeito.