# Qual a diferença entre código de operação (opcode), instrução de máquina, e conjunto de instruções (instruction set)?

Tags: terminologia, assembly, binary, byte, x86

Qual a diferença entre eles? Sei que tanto opcode como conjunto de instruções mostram comandos que existem em cada arquitetura.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

A grosso modo podemos dizer que *opcode* é a instrução, e por óbvio *instruction set* é um conjunto deles. Então a relação e que difere entre eles é basicamente isso.

Acho que não preciso explicar o que é um conjunto, vou falar agora um pouco melhor o que é *opcode*.

Na verdade *opcode* não é bem uma instrução, é uma parte dela. E aqui cabe entender melhor o que é a diferença entre essas duas coisas.

A *instrução de máquina* é como o [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) de linguagens de alto nível. Ela é toda a linha (codificada em algum sistema numérico, em geral binário, ou seja, é uma cadeia de bits) que manda fazer algo e tem um número que define o que será feito e outras informações que dão mais especificidade e dizem com o que aquilo deve ser feito. Podemos dizer, só para facilitar o entendimento, que seria parecido com chamar uma função, onde você tem o nome dela e [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

*Opcode* é a redução de *operation code*. Ele é só a parte que diz qual é a operação a ser feita e estritamente é um número documentado. Mas em Assembly as pessoas usam um mnemônico nomeado em vez de um número. O número dificilmente precisa ocupar mais do que 1 byte, que podemos chamar, informalmente, de "byte principal" da instrução.

Apesar disso, pode-se ter mais de 256 "comandos" (instruções) diferentes ao todo para o processador, então a combinação de alguns bytes faz a instrução. A parte que vem depois do byte principal identifica quais registradores serão afetados, algum parâmetro relacionado à memória se for o caso, ou modos de operação. Em geral o que define essas coisas secundárias são *opcodes* que se tornam específicos usados em conjunto com o principal.

Apenas valores literais ou constantes usados no código não são *opcodes*.

A instrução considera os argumentos e as variações podem ser bem maiores. Por exemplo

```
xor rax, rax
xor rax, rbx
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Opcode.asm).

Temos aí o mesmo primeiro e segundo *opcodes*, mas instruções diferentes porque muda o terceiro.