# Executar função de acordo com a chave do dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, dicionário

Quero que o usuário escolha uma opção e de acordo com a opção escolhida o sistema executa uma função específica. Queria uma solução mais genérica sem um monte de `if`, `elif` e `else`. Pensei em unir a solução a um dicionário, funcionando mais ou menos assim:

```
def funcao1():
    ...
    return ...

def funcao2():
    ...
    return ...

     .
     . 
     .

dicionario_funcoes = {1: funcao1(), 2: funcao2(), 3: funcao3() ... }

escolha = int(input('Escolha uma opcao: '))

lista_funcoes[escolha]
```

Mas isso não funciona, não executa a função conforme a escolha é feita.

Comment: qual é a dúvida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode usar funções de forma direta assim, porque quando cria o dicionário está chamando a função, então o valor armazenado na chave será o resultado da função que é chamada, e aí nada dará certo.

Você tem que armazenar uma função que deseja chamar sem que a chamada ocorra. Com isso você não pode usar os parênteses que é o operador de chamada, armazene apenas o identificador da função na dicionário.

Depois quando for chamar a função deve aplicar os parênteses, porque são eles que fazem a chamada ocorrer usando aquele identificador. E esse identificador pode ser usado com uma variável, conforme estava tentando fazer, só não sabia como chamar.

```
def funcao1():
    return 1
def funcao2():
    return 2

dicionario_funcoes = { 1: funcao1, 2: funcao2 }
escolha = int(input('Escolha uma opcao: '))
print(dicionario_funcoes[escolha]())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/T69xxY). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/hmzsulowha-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/LambdaLike.py).

Não estou fazendo um código robusto, apenas mostrando o mecanismo.

Toda sintaxe da linguagem tem um motivo para existir daquela forma, e sabendo porque ele está lá consegue aprender da forma correta. As coisas não existem na linguagem por acaso ou porque é bonitinho, foi pensado e está na documentação como funciona tudo. No caso os parênteses usados logo após um identificador ou um valor que entregue um identificador é o [operador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) de chamada de função, onde usá-lo depende do que deseja (use quando quer chamar, não use se a intenção não é chamar). Ele não está lá só pra ficar bonito, ele tem uma função específica e pode ser usado em diversos contextos, assim como o `+` é assim, ou outros operadores.

Comment: Verdade,  nao me atentei que no fim eu estava chamando a funcao e precisava executá-la,  entao esqueci dos parênteses, muito obrigado.