# "unsigned int" e "int", qual o mais rápido?

Tags: c, desempenho, tipagem, int

Na linguagem C, entre `unsigned int` e `int`, qual o tipo mais rápido? Eu sei (acho) que `unsigned` pode armazenar números maiores por que `int` reserva um bit (espaço) para o sinal e `unsigned` não. Mas qual o mais rápido na prática?

Comment: Mais rápido para quê?

Comment: Cálculos, incremento e decremento. Mais especificamente em ciclos 'for'.

Comment: (pós-incremeto e pós-decremento também, claro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende da plataforma, mas em geral é igual. Usar o [tipos não sinalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77418/101) é [mais complicado do que parece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101) e você só deve usar se precisar muito e se entender todas as implicações, principalmente quando interagem com tipos sinalizados. Em grade parte dos casos em laços `for` o mais correto é usar [`size_t`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104118/101) e não `int` como todo mundo usa. Mas sempre depende do que está fazendo, e na prática, na maioria dos casos, o resultado é o mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que é size_t? e o que significa "sinalizado" e "não sinalizado"?

Comment: Tradução de *signed* e *unsigned*. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104118/101